# Detect row data change in html (form) table (JavaScript / Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am a reader and getting a lot of help here. This is my first post. 
I know this could be a similar question, but I still could not find answer for it. 
Can someone please help me to write a JavaScript / jquery code:  if a user modifies any of these fields, then the dbFlag value will set to "U" (init. as “N”).  I am struggling to produce the correct code. 
Note: the data rows are populated from DB, so it could be 1 row, or N rows.
Highly appreciate your time and efforts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" id="form1" action="saveData" method="POST">
            <table id="dataTable" border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Badge #</th>
                        <th>turn #</th>
                        <th>Comment</th>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" size="7" name="badge" id="badge" value="000000" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="descMpoint" id="descMpoint2">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>                    
                        </td>
                        <td><textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="2">txt area</textarea></td>             
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="dbFlag" id="dbFlag" value="N" />     
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>
            <span class="tab"><input type="submit" name="updateData" value="Submit" id="updateData"/></span>
            <br><hr>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to use an `.on('change',function(){});` event to capture the change then traverse the dom to update the value: Something like $('input').on('change', function(){$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=dbFlag]').val('U')}); But you need to remove that ID - you can only have unique ID's - you can change to a class to make it easier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the `change` event:

```
$('#form1').on('change', 'input, select, textarea', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="dbFlag"]').val('U');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ng5cZ/) & [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: I really appreciate all your helps. I am implementing now, it works. 
How come the jquery looks simple, but dan hard to write correctly.

Comment: I click the "check", it but it changes back again. I post another question, do you mind taking a look when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, use the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event function.
Note that the function fires when the field in question is unfocused/blurred.

Example:

```
$("#badge").change(function(){
    var currentElement = $(this); //reference to the element that was changed
    //etc. etc.
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfdNs/